# MATLAB: Matrix of dot products

Tags: matlab, matrix, dot-product

I have two matrices, `X` of size `800E3x45` and `W` of size `45x35`. How can I create a matrix of size `800E3x35` where each entry is the dot product of a row of `X` and column of `W`?

Comment: try with `M = X*W`

Comment: Why are your all questions same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that is not best way for reading and understanding code, but you can do it in vectorized view using the next formula:

```
res = cell2mat(  arrayfun(@(y) arrayfun( @(x) dot( X(y,:), W(:,x)), 1:size(W,2)), ...
              (1:size(X,1))', 'UniformOutput', false) )
```

Explanation:

1. We need to take `dot( X(y,:), W(:x))` - for each row of X (y means row number) we takes dot for all the columns of W (x is column of W)
2. Use `arrayfun` (inner) for getting each column of W
3. Use `arrayfun` (extern) for getting each row of X.
4. We get result in cell array, so lets convert it to numeric matrix - use `cell2mat'

---

P.S. I think there is can be more elegant solution, smth using `bsxfun` but this is the first I can imagine.